# select one column from one table and other columns from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the tables :

```
1. Users : user_id, user_name    
2. Transaction : user_id, transaction_number, transaction_date
```

I want to get the user_id, transaction_number, transaction_date for a particular transaction_date. The first table may contain repeated user_id for different dates and may not contain all user_id for a particular date. The result must contain all user_ids and its transaction_number and transaction dates are null if the user_id has no any transaction entries in the transaction table.

For an example :

```
user_id             transaction_number            transaction_date
    1                    10                           12/04/2013
    2                    0                            12/04/2013
    3                    0                            12/04/2013
```

It shows there are only 3 users and only user_id 1 have transaction in 12/04/2013.

Comment: Have you used [Mysql Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html)? where is your query which you tried?

Comment: I have found the solution.

Comment: I have found the solution :
select * from Transaction right outer join Users on Transaction.user_id = Users.user_id and Transaction.transaction_date = 'Apr 12 2013 12:00AM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from Transaction right outer join Users on Transaction.user_id = Users.user_id and Transaction.transaction_date = 'Apr 12 2013 12:00AM'

Answer (score 1):

You can replace transaction_number with 0 if it is null depending on the type of database you are using.

```
Select u.User_id, transactions.transaction_number, '12/04/2013' as transaction_date
from Users u
left join ( Select user_id, Sum(transaction_number)
             from Transaction
             where transaction_date = '12/04/2013'
             Group By user_id
            ) transactions
            on transactions.User_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

List all users with transactions if any.Use left join.

```
select users.user_id,users.user_name,transaction.transaction_number, transaction.date from users left join transaction on users.user_id = transaction.user_id
```

Comment: The result contain all rows in transaction table